# How to call the python library as an external script in Node-RED

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, node-red, ibm-cloud-tools

I am using virtual cloud from iotify.io and using execute node. I am not able to call a python script. How to run a python script in Node-RED?

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea about iotify.io but if you are on a Pi as your tags suggest, i.e. NodeRed is running on the Pi, you can have something like this in the exec node: 
`/usr/bin/python /home/pi/HelloWorld.py`. If NodeRed is not running on the Pi though, the exec will execute where it is actually running so it won't find that file.  You would need the script on the server where NodeRed is running.
HTH
Maeve

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, @amadain!